# Como alterar rótulos de dados no ggplot - R

Tags: banco-de-dados, ggplot2, r

Tenho um banco de dados com porcentagens de "completude", os dados estão organizados por Ano e Município, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é fazer gráficos (em série histórica) para cada município, onde apresentariam a MÉDIA das das TAXAS ao longo dos anos.

Estou usando essa função para melhorar a aparência do gráfico:

```
tema_plot <- function(){ 
  theme_gray() %+replace%    #replace elements we want to change
    theme(
      axis.title.y=element_blank(),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold", size = 10, color = "black"),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold")
    )
}
```

E o script para gerar o gráfico é esse:

```
TAXA_IDENTIDADE %>%
  group_by(Cod_Municipio, Ano) %>% 
  summarise(Total = mean(Taxa_escolaridade)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Total, y = Ano, label = Total))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_label()+
  geom_text(aes(label = signif(Total, digits = 3)))+
  ggtitle("Completitude: Escolaridade 2006 - 2022")+
  coord_flip()
```

Ele está gerando um gráfico com rótulos sobrepostos conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: Gráfico]

Agora as dúvidas:
1 - Como altero os rótulos de cada coluna para que não fiquem sobrepostos?

2 - Como altero o "formato" do número para que ele tenha apenas 3 digitos e o rótulo ter apenas 3 casas. Ex : 0,97. (usei esse código 'label = signif(Total, digits = 3)' e não deu certo.

3 - Existe forma de automatizar e fazer o R rodar os gráficos para todos os municipios?

Comment: Poderia compartilhar uma amostra dos seus dados com `dput`?

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que a solução abaixo ajude-o a solucionar o problema.

**Dúvida: Como altero os rótulos de cada coluna para que não fiquem sobrepostos?**

Os rótulos estão sendo gerados sobrepostos, pois há mais de um valor da variável `Taxa_escolaridade` para cada ano (já que há valores de mais de um município por ano). Além disso, para gerar os rótulos de cada ano, não há necessidade de utilizar conjuntamente o `geom_label` e o `geom_text`, você pode optar por um ou por outro.

**Dúvida: Como altero o "formato" do número para que ele tenha apenas 3 digitos e o rótulo ter apenas 3 casas. Ex : 0,97. (usei esse código 'label = signif(Total, digits = 3)' e não deu certo.**

Para especificar o número de casas decimais, você pode utilizar a função `round()` e definir a quantidade de casas decimais. Por exemplo, se o valor é `0.9723` e você defini `digits = 3`, então o número é arredondado para `0.972`

**Dúvida: Existe forma de automatizar e fazer o R rodar os gráficos para todos os municípios?**

Há várias formas de automatizar a geração dos gráficos no R.

- Se você deseja gerar os gráficos para cada município de forma individual, você pode utilizar, em conjunto, as funções `group_by()` e `group_map()`, disponíveis no pacote `dplyr`. Neste caso, seria interessante você utilizar, por exemplo, a função `ggsave()` ([consulte a documentação](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html)) para ir salvando localmente, no seu computador, os gráficos em algum formato de imagem (e.g., PNG ou JPEG).
- Se você deseja gerar os gráficos para cada município de modo que fiquem em um mesmo gráfico (considerando que você não tenha um número muito grande de municípios), você pode utilizar a função `facet_wrap()` do pacote `ggplot2`.

Em resumo, o trecho de código abaixo ilustra como você pode organizar os rótulos, especificar o número de casas decimais e automatizar a geração dos gráficos no *R*.

```r
# Carregando os pacotes utilizados
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Defindo tema para estilizar o gráfico 
tema_plot <- function(){ 
  theme_gray() %+replace%   
    theme(
      axis.title.y=element_blank(),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_text(face = "bold", size = 10, color = "black"),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold")
    )
}

# Gerando base de dados para o exemplo
TAXA_IDENTIDADE <-
  tibble::tibble(
    Cod_Municipio = rep(c(110001:110004), each = 14),
    Ano = rep(c(2007:2010, 2013:2022), 4),
    Taxa_escolaridade = runif(14 * 4, min = 0.75, max = 1)
  )

# Estimando a média para cada município e ano (caso haja mais de um valor para a variável Taxa_escolaridade)
TAXA_IDENTIDADE <- TAXA_IDENTIDADE %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Cod_Municipio, Ano) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(Total = mean(Taxa_escolaridade, na.rm = TRUE),
                   .groups = "keep") |> 
  dplyr::mutate(Ano = as.factor(Ano |> unique() |> sort()))

# Visualizando os dados por município com a facet_wrap()
ggplot(data = TAXA_IDENTIDADE, 
       mapping = aes(y = Total, x = Ano))+
  geom_bar(alpha = 0.5, stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_label(mapping = aes(label = round(Total, digits = 3)), size = 2.5) +
  facet_wrap(~ Cod_Municipio, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") + 
  ggtitle("Completitude: Escolaridade 2006 - 2022") +
  tema_plot()
```

[Exemplo de séries históricas geradas por município](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynJFn.png)

```r
# Gerando os gráficos municipais (de modo individual)
TAXA_IDENTIDADE %>%
  group_by(Cod_Municipio) %>%
  group_map(~ {
    ggplot(
      data = .x,
      mapping = aes(y = Total, x = Ano)
    ) +
      geom_bar(
        alpha = 0.5,
        stat = "identity",
        position = "dodge"
      ) +
      geom_label(
        mapping = aes(label = round(Total, digits = 3)),
        size = 4
      ) + 
      ggtitle( 
        glue::glue("Completitude: Escolaridade 2006 - 2022",
                   " (Município: {.x$Cod_Municipio[1]})")
        ) +
      tema_plot()
  }, .keep = TRUE)
```

[Exemplo de série histórica gerada para município 110001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dFHC.png)

[Exemplo de série histórica gerada para município 110002](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMx6I.png)

[Exemplo de série histórica gerada para município 110003](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPYvm.png)

[Exemplo de série histórica gerada para município 110004](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfARI.png)